# LdapConnection timeout vs SearchRequest timeout

Tags: c#, ldap, ldapconnection

Which one takes precedence?

Say you create a new LdapConnection and set its Timeout property to 30 seconds.

```
 LdapConnection ldapConn = new LdapConnection(hostName + ":" + port)
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            }
```

Later when you submit a SearchRequest, you also specify a timeout of 30 seconds again as follows:

```
  var response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(req, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

The connection obviously lives longer than the request so I would expect the second timeout to be associated with the request, with the first one associated with the connection.  Does not make any sense when I think about it, so I ask you the experts.  Since the connection was created with a timeout, does it's timeout take precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection times out 30 seconds after you last use it. The search request times out 30 seconds after you submit it. If you submit a search request 31 seconds after you last used the connection, you will get a connection timeout. If you submit it sooner, it will time out after 30 seconds, as a search timeout, as the connection is still in use for the search.

Comment: Thanks,  To add, connection timeout also determines how long we need to wait after attempting to bind.  This is what I found later.